# How would the military fight magicians?

Tags: magic, military, tactics

This is a follow-up question to this one: [How would the police fight magicians?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/89273/how-would-the-police-fight-magicians)
Differences about the powers of the two are *italic*.

In my story there are two guys, each equipped with a unique, magic-like ability.

The first one can emit the elements fire, water, ice *and electricity* from any inch of his body. It does not cost him any kind of energy, but it is (a little bit) exhausting (think throwing a ball for a "fire shot"). It hast to be attached to his body, but he can throw/shoot it. Using ice, he can form nearly anything he wants (if it holds). Everything he creates follows normal rules of nature, fire is hot, ice is cold, etc (it can also melt, if he doesn't focus on keeping it cold). He is able to withstand to his own created elements, *as well as all others. That means he is completely immune to heat and cold as well as electricity (but not drowning!).*

The other on has the ability to lift/shatter objects without touching them (like a jedi) and create a "force shield". Once again it doesn't drain any energy and is mildly exhausting, depending on the size and number of object and speed/velocity. Between him and the object can only be air, or the like, as solids would block the range of his power (but he could probably shatter any obstacle in the way). His "force shield" is just an extension of his other power, he can create a space where all kinetic energy is stopped, like bullets. Only one and it is a plane not bigger than a *car* and while it stops gas and water and air, it cannot be perfectly aligned with solid material like a hole in a wall so it's kinda useless against gas and the likes. *The size and weight of the objects he can manipulate as well as the number are pretty high, as an example he can lift two cars, change their tires and put them safely down. (2 times 4 times 5[bolts] + 2 times 8[tires] = 56 objects with ease)

Without the need for precision he is able to lift anything about the weight of a small house.*

Not sure, if it is relevant, but their powers are loosely tied to their emotions, the "elementalist" leaks water when sad, emits heat when angry, cold when sad *and electricity when exited (not deadly)*. The "jedi" is more powerful when strong emotions are involved, but looses precision.

**Apart from these two individuals, the world is the same as ours and the public does not know about them. The military however knows about their powers, basically as much as I wrote here!**

To clarify:
I am NOT asking you how to kill/defeat the two, I already know that.
I am NOT asking you to write a scenario.
I am NOT asking you what the military would ultimately decide to do.

**Are there rules/standard tactics for dealing with these two unusual threats?**

Comment: This is the same question that you already asked. Having it so that one of your magicians also uses electric doesn't substantially change the question. The correct thing to do when you have a question that you are trying to get reopened is to edit the question, not ask it again.

Comment: @sphennings Well, 1. I edited the question and I'm hopeful it will get reopened. 2. I'm asking about the military, which is - as far as I know - pretty different from the police. The electricity change is just because the military encounter happen later in the story. I don't think it's a duplicate, if you think so, then please explain since I believe police and military are fundamentally different.

Comment: If nobody knows about them there is no way for a plan to be in place. Since nobody knows about them their abilities don't matter to the question.

Comment: Aaaah sorry, I meant the public doesn't know, the military does know what they're up against. -I'll edit my question - sry

Comment: @Sevidral Your question may not be an exact duplicate of your original but is close enough that all the reasons why the first should be closed would apply to this one as well. Until the first one is opened, you shouldn't ask a very closely related question with the same elements.

Comment: If you are asking how does the military plan on dealing with them this is about a scenario set in a world and not about building the world itself.

Comment: @A.C.A.C. In the meta discussion about that question people agreed it was fine in its current state, it was simply too old to attract enough votes to reopen, that's why I thought its okay to post this question.

Comment: @sphennings I'm asking about possible strategies/tactics, which WB clearly says is alright...
I get the feel, people are searching for reasons to close questions rather than actually helping others.... It's hard to follow the rules if everyone says different things and there is little to no agreement, so this is my final attempt.

Comment: If you want to bring attention to an old question you can edit the question to improve its clarity. That will bring it to the top of the message queue. Once you have 20 reputation you can bring up the question in chat to draw attention to it. The wrong way to bring attention to a question you have asked is to post a duplicate to it.

Comment: If you are unsure about asking questions you can use the sandbox on [meta.worldbuilding.se] to get feedback on your questions before asking them.

Comment: I don't think it's a duplic-  
You know what, fine, you won. I read all the rules I could find, I tried to create questions that followed those rules and I still believe I succeeded with that. But even the highest rep users on this site don't agree with each other what is and isn't allowed and frankly - it's kinda ridiculous. It took way more time to discuss how to formulate it "correct" than anyone could ever spend answering it. Farewell and sorry, I never intended to steal anyone's time with this.

Comment: @L.Dutch somehow the duplicate link is a 404

Answer (score 3):

There are rules, yes.  They are all custom tailored to the specific events at hand, and cannot be stated in generality.

For example, one of the biggest questions would be whether lethal force had already been authorized.  Every major military provides rules of engagement which specify when lethal force is permitted.  Some missions come with rules that literally state "you can't shoot them until they shoot at you."  Others state that the secrets regarding the mission are more important than the lives of those around you.

Some situations may call for an elite team like a Seal team or a Ranger team to go in and resolve the situation.  Other situations may call for the deployment of large numbers of foot soldiers to apply pressure.  Others call for launching a few cruise missiles from hundreds of miles away and obliterating the threat before the threat even knows the missiles are there.  The response will be night-and-day different if these two start raising havoc in the middle of a massive corn field in Kansas versus if their first notable appearance is killing security personnel at the White House.

It's actually kind of funny, but it is *intentionally* impossible to provide you with one doctrine for these circumstances.  You can actually prove that if any government were to provide a "doctrine for unusual threats," a competing government could use that doctrine to identity a way to exploit it for an advantage.  A government that has such a doctrine must keep it secret, or they are at a disadvantage.

Comment: Wow, an actual answer :3
That's actually a really good point, dammit XD Those cruise missiles sound like a good idea, but only if the "jedi" (dang they need names) does not/too late notice them^^
Thank you!

Comment: You can't plan for the unknown. You can make an educated guess about what will likely happen and attempt to prepare for that. I doubt any modern military has any plan for suddenly fighting wizards. If they do it would be little more than "use your judgement, and figure it out as you go along".